# How to create a table with blank borders in Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

I cannot seem to find any way to create a table with blank borders in Word 2003. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create a table, put the cursor in one of its cells and select Table Properties in the Table menu. In the dialog that appears, there's a button for Borders and Shading near the bottom, click it. In the new dialog that appears you can set the border to None.

[image: screenshot showing dialogs used to change the border style of an existing table to None]

If you would like to make this a one-step process, you could define your own borderless table style by selecting Table Autoformat... on the Table menu and selecting User-defined table styles in the pull-down menu under Category: in the dialog that appears and then clicking the New button. Another dialog box will then appear and you can and and define your custom table style and then save it for future use when inserting tables.

[image: screenshot show how to create a user defined table style]